# Need multiple count of id in single row from a column of a table using different criteria

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, pivot

I have one table with following columns

id = e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6...

status = e.g. Available/Not Available

cityName = e.g = Ahmedabad

I wrote below query and got the output as i required but i want it in some different format

```
SELECT count(id) as 'Count', status, cityName  FROM table_name
    WHERE cityName like 'Ahmedabad'
    GROUP BY status ;
```

**Output : -**

```
----------------------
Count|status|cityname
----------------------
100|Available|Ahmeadabad

200|Not Available|Ahmeadabad
```

**Output i want :-**

```
--------------------------------
Available|Not Available|cityname
--------------------------------
100|200|Ahmeadabad
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(status = 'Available', 1, 0)) AS `Available`,
SUM(IF(status = 'Not Available', 1, 0)) AS `Not_Available`,
cityName
FROM
table_name
GROUP BY cityName
```

Please ask if anything is unclear about the query.

Alternatively, if you just want that single city, you can omit the GROUP BY

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(status = 'Available', 1, 0)) AS `Available`,
SUM(IF(status = 'Not Available', 1, 0)) AS `Not_Available`,
cityName
FROM
table_name
WHERE cityName = 'Ahmeadabad'
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic approach is to use SUM(CASE WHEN...)

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Available' then 1 else 0 end) AS `Available`, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Not Available' then 1, 0 end) AS `Not_Available`, 
cityName 
FROM 
table_name 
GROUP BY cityName
```